# Let $a < b $ be real numbers and consider set T = $\mathbb Q \ \cap \ [a,b].$ Show $\sup \ T =b$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, real-numbers

Let $a < b $ be real numbers and consider set T = $\mathbb Q\cap  [a,b].$ Show $\sup T =b$

*I needed help checking if my proof is correct. If it isn't correct can you please provide the correct proof or a hint in the correct direction.*

> Proof. $T$ is the set of all rational numbers x such that $a \le x \le b.$ 
>   Let $\sup T = \alpha.$
>
> Assume $\alpha < b.$ Since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb R$ there exists a rational $r$ such that $a < \alpha <r< b .$ This means $r \in [a,b] $ and $r< \alpha$ which is a contradiction.
>
> Assume $b< \alpha.$ Since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb R$ there exists a rational r such that $b  <r < \alpha$ but this implies that $r$ is an upper bound of $[a,b]$. However since  $r < \alpha$ this means that $\alpha $ cannot be a supremum of $[a,b]$, which is also a contradiction.
>
> Hence $b =  \alpha $ and is the supremum of $T.$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.  You're basically using the density of $\Bbb Q$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: You don't need the second case: $b$ is by definition an upper bound of $\mathbf Q\cap[a,b]$, so the *least* upper bound is necessarily  $\le b$.

Comment: @Bernard Yeah thanks! I didn't realize that...